# Hibernate OGM over Spring-Data is valid?

Tags: spring-data, hibernate-ogm, nosql

I want to create an project and using `MongoDB` and `Neo4J`, both databases are need to use. Now the day's `Hibernate OGM` concept was launch and support provide for all NoSQL databases. If i am go for `Hibernate OGM` they used JPA apis for implementation and it is easy user for Hibernate users. If i am go for Spring-Data, we need to configure both `Spring-Data MongoDB` and `Spring-Data Neo4j` and use `Spring-Data` apis for that. My team is confuse for which technology we go `Hibernate OGM` or `Spring-Data`. We focus on some points and Go for `Spring-Data`. Points are as below:

1. `Spring-Data` is a early concept, the support for `Spring-Data` is easily provide at online forums but `Hibernate OGM` is new.
2. `Spring-Data` have various features for NoSQL databases, but for Hibernate OGM we are not sure all feature are provided that mention in [this slide.](http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/java-persistence-frameworks-for-mongodb)
3. `Hibernate OGM` use JPA queries and JPA queries translate according to NoSQL vendor query and i think this cause performance issue. But in Spring-Data we easily user `Cypher Queries` and `Mongo Template`.
4. I am also confuse for `Hibernate OGM` have full support for Graph Db feature like maintain attributes of relationship?

Please suggest me for which technology we need to go.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/23168401/18122.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Spring Data MongoDB and Hibernate OGM for MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163853/whats-the-difference-between-spring-data-mongodb-and-hibernate-ogm-for-mongodb)

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to use two different NoSQL databases on a same project, it's probably because you really really need of their uniq features (geo-spatial queries on MongoDB, being able to execute graph traversals for Neo4j, and so on).

So Hibernate OGM is clearly NOT for you. You can use directly native API of Mongo and Neo4j. Or you can use Spring Data that claims to provide a consistent programming model (but **not** a single API).