# Neo4j OGM frameworks

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm, hibernate-ogm

I'new to NEO4J and working around [Neo4J OGM](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-ogm/#_neo4j_ogm), to my understanding this is the framework that is associated with Spring Data Neo4j. There's, however, Hibernate OGM, also supporting Neo4J. Is anyone aware of the differences between the two, or can point to a comparison article?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23163853/whats-the-difference-between-spring-data-mongodb-and-hibernate-ogm-for-mongodb/40548118#40548118 The question in the link refers to MongoDB but the answers can be applied to your question as well (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Object/Grid Mapper (OGM) adds Java Persistence API (JPA) to NoSQL databases. I use OGM with MongoDB and it works very well on JBoss WildFly 12.0.0.Final.

This is the page I refer to a lot:

[Hibernate OGM 5.3.1.Final: Reference Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.3#_how_to_build_support_for_a_data_store)

See section 11. "11. Neo4j"

> Neo4j is a robust (fully ACID) transactional property graph database.
>   This kind of databases are suited for those type of problems that can
>   be represented with a graph like social relationships or road maps for
>   example.

Comment: I'm well aware of the references. I expect an answer from someone who has gone through the pain of using both Neo4J OGM and Hibernate OGM with Neo4J, in practice and has drawn some lessons from it.

Comment: Why burden yourself with Spring Data Neo4j unless you're already using Spring.